# nested xml data not getting in excel as output while using xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to translate xml data into excel using xslt template. But i'm getting only headers, not data. Please check the below xml data and xslt template and my C# code for your reference.

example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<projects>
  <project>
    <name>Shock</name>
    <language>Ruby</language>
    <owner>Brian May</owner>
    <state>New</state>
    <Date>31/10/2008 0:00:00</Date>
  </project>
  <project>
    <name>Shock1</name>
    <language>Ruby1</language>
    <owner>Brian May1</owner>
    <state>New1</state>
    <Date>30/10/2008 0:00:00</Date>
  </project>
</projects>
```

test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook>
      <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
          <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
          <Borders />
          <Font />
          <Interior />
          <NumberFormat />
          <Protection />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s21">
          <Font ss:Size="22" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s22">
          <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s23">
          <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s24">
          <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1" />
        </Style>
      </Styles>
      <Worksheet ss:Name="Page1">
        <Table>
          <xsl:call-template name="XMLToXSL" />
        </Table>
      </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="XMLToXSL">
    <Row ss:Index="1" >
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">name</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">language</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">owner</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">state</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
    <xsl:for-each select="/projects">
      <xsl:for-each select="/project">
        <Row ss:Index="1">
          <Cell ss:Index="2">
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="name" />
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2">
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="language" />
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2">
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="owner" />
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2">
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="state" />
            </Data>
          </Cell>
          <Cell ss:Index="2">
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="Date" />
            </Data>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="DataList">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

C# code:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(@"C:\Xmls\example.xml");
XslCompiledTransform xct = new XslCompiledTransform();
xct.Load(@"C:\Templates\Test.xsl");
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\Outputs\output.xls", null);
writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'");
xct.Transform(xdoc, null, writer);
writer.Close();
```

Excel output.xls:

```
|  name  |  language  |  owner  |  state  |  Date   |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

But my expected output should be as,

```
|  name  |  language  |  owner    |  state  |        Date        |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Shock  | Ruby       | Brian May | New     | 31/10/2008 0:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Shock1 | Ruby1      | Brian May1| New1    | 30/10/2008 0:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently it is printing headers alone in excel,
How to get the data into excel row-wise.

Comment: Try adding a writer.Flush() before closing the writer.

Comment: As well as Martin's answer, you are also not setting `ss:Index` correctly on any of the rows or cells. All your rows are currently numbered 1, but the should be numbered 1, 2, 3... and similarly all you cells are numbered 2, but these also need to be numbered 1, 2, 3.... Having said that, if you remove all instances of `ss:index` you should still be OK as then Excel will treat everything as consecutive. You only need `ss:index` if you want to skip over some rows/cells to leave them blank.

Comment: Thank you Tim :) I've followed Martin's replace code and removed Index things. It got worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `xsl:for-each select="/project"` with `xsl:for-each select="project"`.

I would also simplify the C# to use

```
XslCompiledTransform xct = new XslCompiledTransform();
xct.Load(@"C:\Templates\Test.xsl");
xct.Transform(@"C:\Xmls\example.xml", @"C:\Outputs\output.xls");
```

although I don't think the code you have causes the problem, it is the XSLT that has the wrong XPath.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've tried this. not working. Excel itself not opening if i replace as you suggested.